# How To Iterate Through Objects (Saved in List) Using For Loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, callable

I am running an API to grab some information from a website where I am storing the information in a list '[]'.  How can I run a for loop through this information to:

1) Iterate through the list of objects in a for loop (specifically comparing one objects text
2) If one value of the object equals a 1 word, save whole object into a new list

I have tried running a for loop through the list/objects but get the error ''list' object is not callable'

```
tree = Et.fromstring(response.content)
for child in tree.findall('meterConsumption'):
    for audit in child.findall('audit'):
        for creator in audit.findall('createdBy'): 
    for ID in child.findall('id'):
        print ('Entry ID: ',ID.text)
    for use in child.findall('usage'):
        print ('Use: ',use.text)
    for cost in child.findall('cost'):
        print ('Cost: ',cost.text)
    for startdate in child.findall('startDate'):
        print ('Startdate: ',startdate.text)
    for enddate in child.findall('endDate'):
        print ('Enddate: ',enddate.text)



    #save object to list
    allentries.append(Entry(ID.text,
                            use.text,
                            cost.text,
                            startdate.text,
                            enddate.text,
                            creator.text))

for x in allentries():
    print (x.entryid)
```

I am looking to get a list of all key value pairs in the object.  For example it would like:

1. Id[1], use[1], cost[1], startdate[1], enddate[1], creator[1]
2. Id[2], use[2], cost[2], startdate[2], enddate[2], creator[2]
3. Id[3], use[3], cost[3], startdate[3], enddate[3], creator[3]

The say from this, if creator == "human".append to all info from this object to a new object list

Comment: What's the purpose of the () in `allentries()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triple for loops followed a for loop for child.findall('id') will result in a compile-time error called as `identation error`.

```
for child in tree.findall('meterConsumption'):
  for audit in child.findall('audit'):
    for creator in audit.findall('createdBy'):
  #identation error 
 for ID in child.findall('id'):
    print ('Entry ID: ', ID.text)
```

List object is not callable means u trying to call list-objects. 
allentries is a list & u are trying to call a list by using `()`.
Remove this  `()`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the `'list' object is not callable` error when you try to call a list like you would call a function. That's happening in your second last line:

```
for x in allentries():
    print (x.entryid)
```

Since `allentries` is your list, tacking on a `()` at the end of it is the syntax for "calling" it, which doesn't make sense for objects that aren't functions. So the correct syntax is:

```
for x in allentries:
    print (x.entryid)
```

Per your second question, I'd suggest looking into `pandas` DataFrames as handy ways to work with tabular data in Python. Since `child.findall()` gives you a list of objects that you're extracting text from with `.text`, you can pass a dictionary of lists to the `DataFrame` constructor like so:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize empty dataframe
allentries = pd.DataFrame()

for child in tree.findall('meterConsumption'):
    for audit in child.findall('audit'):
        for creator in audit.findall('createdBy'): 

            # Also touched up your indentation
            for ID in child.findall('id'):
                print ('Entry ID: ',ID.text)
            for use in child.findall('usage'):
                print ('Use: ',use.text)
            for cost in child.findall('cost'):
                print ('Cost: ',cost.text)
            for startdate in child.findall('startDate'):
                print ('Startdate: ',startdate.text)
            for enddate in child.findall('endDate'):
                print ('Enddate: ',enddate.text)

            # Use list comprehensions to extract text attributes
            allentries.append({
                'ID': [ID.text for ID in child.findall('id')],
                'use': [use.text for use in child.findall('use')],
                'cost': [cost.text for cost in child.findall('cost')],
                'startdate': [startdate.text for startdate in child.findall('startDate')],
                'enddate': [enddate.text for enddate in child.findall('endDate')]
            })

# Display the final dataframe
print(allentries)
```